# Soloader getting UnsatisfiedLinkError in android 10

Tags: java, android, react-native, unsatisfiedlinkerror

Actually, I'm uploaded my app in PlayStore, but in dispositive with Android 10, I received the error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.doLoadLibraryBySoName (SoLoader.java:1098)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoNameImpl (SoLoader.java:914)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibraryBySoName (SoLoader.java:826)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary (SoLoader.java:773)
  at com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader.loadLibrary (SoLoader.java:743)
  at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.loadLibrary (HermesExecutor.java:25)
  at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.<clinit> (HermesExecutor.java:19)
  at com.facebook.hermes.reactexecutor.HermesExecutor.loadLibrary (HermesExecutor.java:23)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory (ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:394)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build (ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:344)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.createReactInstanceManager (ReactNativeHost.java:95)
  at expo.modules.ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.createReactInstanceManager (ReactNativeHostWrapperBase.kt:32)
  at com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost.getReactInstanceManager (ReactNativeHost.java:42)
  at com.sigaa.MainApplication.onCreate (MainApplication.java:66)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1190)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:6540)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400 (ActivityThread.java:220)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1883)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:224)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7520)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:539)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

I viewed various questions about the problem, but I have not resolved this. Any solutions?

My [package.json](https://gist.github.com/matheuswr89/022275ef25d7faf9d167bf413ef07629) file.

My [eas.json](https://gist.github.com/matheuswr89/9fa558e85435a821625fe72486f6e80e) file.